# Why Emacs (dired+) asks me twice to delete file?

Tags: files, deletion

windows 10, Emacs 26.1, `dired+`

Suppose I want to delete (move to trash) file in `dired` mode.

<kbd>D</kbd>

Emacs asks me:

[image]

I press <kbd>y</kbd>

and now it's asking me again to `kill` file.

[image]

Why Emacs asks me twice?
I want to answer only once to delete (move to trash) the file.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Dired, beyond the fact that you initiated the deletion there.

Comment: You apparently neglected, in your description/recipe, to say that you also, sometime prior to trying to trash the file, visited it, so there is a buffer visiting it. (And you neglected to say that you have option `delete-by-moving-to-trash` set to non-`nil`.

Comment: FWIW those screenshots are really hard to read due to small size of text.

Comment: @Reid 1. Trash "file_name"? (y/n), 2. Kill buffer of "file_name", too? (y/n)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So when you open a file it creates a 'buffer' with the file's contents. The first yes moves the physical file to the trash. But the 'buffer' is still loaded in Emacs. If you say no to the second option you can still view the file in Emacs even though it's in the trash can. If this is too redundant I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546639/dired-x-how-to-set-kill-buffer-of-too-to-yes-without-confirmation) has the proper solution (although admittedly I have not tested it myself).

Comment: Yes, this is because before delete file I open it. So if NOT open file before delete, than Emacs ask me about delete only once

Comment: Exactly, @Alexei. In Emacs, a buffer is not the same thing as a file. This a Good Thing. This may seem like a nuisance at first, but it's really very useful, even powerful, to be able to completely separate what is in Emacs' memory from what is on disk.